# Python - Sort a Pandas Dataframe twice

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I would like to sort a Pandas dataframe twice the same way excel does. Given the following `df`:

```
Name  Date  
John 13/01  
Mike 13/01  
John 15/01  
John 14/01  
Mike 12/01
```

When adding the following code:

```
df=df.sort_values(['Date','Name'], ascending=[True, True])
```

I would expect the following result:

```
Name Date  
John 13/01  
John 14/01  
John 15/01  
Mike 12/01  
Mike 13/01
```

I'm getting nothing close to this result with the code above. Any idea where's the mistake?

Many thanks!

Comment: make sure that your date is a pandas `DatetimeIndex` and not a string.

Comment: Order of column names matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need swap columns, because first sort by `Name` and then by `Date`, `ascending=[True, True]` should be removed, because default parameter:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Name','Date'])
print (df)
   Name   Date
0  John  13/01
3  John  14/01
2  John  15/01
4  Mike  12/01
1  Mike  13/01
```